# Whats the meaing of 1%{?dist} in SPEC file in RPM package

Tags: linux, fedora, packaging, rpm

What does 1%{?dist} mean? 
What does %{?} mean?
I didn't find the meaning of this anywhere

```
Name:           hello
Version:        2.8
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        The "Hello World" program from GNU
License:        GPLv3+
URL:            http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/%{name}
Source0:        http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/%{name}/%{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
BuildRequires: gettext
Requires(post): info
Requires(preun): info
%description
```

The "Hello World" program, done with all bells and whistles of a proper FOSS 
project, including configuration, build, internationalization, help files, etc.

```
%prep
%autosetup
%build
%configure
make %{?_smp_mflags}
```

Answer (score 19):

The question mark is for conditional evaluation. When a macro has no value rpm leaves the macro tag in place by default. The `?` tells rpm to remove the macro tag if there is no value and substitute the value of the macro if there is one:

```
$ rpm -E 'foo:%{foo}'$'\n''bar:%{?bar}'
foo:%{foo}
bar:

$ rpm -D'foo foov' -E 'foo:%{foo}'$'\n''bar:%{?bar}'
foo:foov
bar:

$ rpm -D'foo foov' -D'bar barv' -E 'foo:%{foo}'$'\n''bar:%{?bar}'
foo:foov
bar:barv
```

So, as RahulKrishnanRA says, `%{?dist}` says use the distribution tag (`rh`, `el5`, `rf`, etc.) when one exists and an empty string when it doesn't.

Unfortunately, the only documentation link I have about this is not a particularly good one. http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/ConditionalBuilds and the linked manual page.

Answer (score 2):

The `{?dist}` tag is used to mark the distribution revision of a package

Comment: A little more details abut the meaning of the `?` would have been helpful, as done in the other answer...